# how do i add active class in div using JS?

Tags: javascript

```js
let wrapper = document.querySelector(".form-wrap");
let loginLink = document.querySelector(".login-link");
let registerLink = document.querySelector(".register-link");

registerLink.addEventListener("click", () => {
  wrapper.classList.add("active");
});

loginLink.addEventListener("click", () => {
  wrapper.classList.remove("active");
});
```

```html
<div class="form-wrap">
  <a href="" class="login-link">Login</a>
  <a href="" class="register-link">Register</a>
```

both anchor tag are inside the div

adding active to the div(form-wrap)=>(class="form-wrap active")

Comment: Unless you use `event.preventDefault()`, clicking on the anchor will follow the link and reload the page.

Comment: Or change them to `href="#"`

Comment: Or change them to `href="javascript:void(0)"` if you don't want it scrolling to the top of the page